# How to set a execution limit time to a thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, interrupt

I'm creating a connection thread, and I need to kill her if exceed a predetermined execution limit time.

Example: If the connection attempt time exceed 5 seconds, interrupt the Connection Thread.

How can I implement this? :(

I'm using the Android SDK (java).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are using sockets you can set the timeout limit like this:

```
Socket s1 = new Socket();
s1.setSoTimeout(200);
s1.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.2", 1254), 200);
```

If you wanna put a timelimit in the thread, you can use Executors.

```
try {
  int timeout = 5;
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(new Task()), timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        executor.shutdown();
 } catch (Exception e) {
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about this all wrong. If you ever feel like you need to kill a thread, that means that thread is doing something you don't want it to do. That means that thread is *broken* and should be fixed. You don't want to "reach in" to a thread from the outside and make it do what you want it to do. You want to code that thread from the inside so it does what, and only what, you actually want done. Threads cooperate to accomplish a job. A thread should *never* be coded to do work that is not desired to be done.

In most cases, you can just leave the thread alone. Just stop waiting for it or try something else too. Perhaps you might set some flag or give the thread some indication that it's work is no longer needed and have the thread check for that indication from time to time so it can gracefully terminate itself.

Is the thread doing something actually harmful that *must* be stopped? If so, fix it in the thread.

Comment: Arguably, having a thread on a smartphone continuously try to connect to the internet can be harmful. Apps on Android generally keep running until you kill them from within the settings window or the phone reboots. And depending on the permissions given to the app, it could actually use the 3G connection's bandwidth too if no wifi is in range. It'd be best to get the connection attempt to terminate so the thread can stop gracefully.

Comment: @Ghostkeeper Then don't code a thread to continuously try to connect! Code it to try once.